# Google Maps Photo Tours 3D Zoom in animation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Check out this link:

https://www.google.co.in/maps/preview#!q=Mumbai%2C+Maharashtra&data=!1m4!1m3!1d244728!2d73.022606!3d19.042158!4m11!1m10!4m8!1m3!1d117507!2d72.5797426!3d23.0203457!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!17b1

If you click on any of the images displayed at the bottom there's a brilliant zooming in animation to the photo tour. Really interested to know how Google is doing this and how the same can be implemented using their APIs.

Pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated!

Thanks!